# Passing a value between services in Angular5 using RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

I am trying to pass an access_token , which is declared in userService service, and its value is set in register.component.ts. Then I need to access the value of the access_token in another service (httpService). I decided to use BehavioralSubject for that matter but somehow i cannot retrieve updated value of the token in httpService. The code excerpt below.

**User.service.ts** -> here i declare the access_token

```
 access_token = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
```

**Register.component.ts** -> here i successfully assign the value to access_token

```
 onRegister(form){
    this.httpService.registerByEmail(this.email, this.password )
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        this.popupService.popupScreen.next('messenger');
        this.httpService.loginByEmail(this.email, this.password)
        .subscribe(response1 => {
          this.userService.access_token.next(response1['access_token']);
          console.log('access_token Component', this.userService.access_token);    --> here it console.logs the correct token
        },
        error => {
          console.log('error', error);
        }
      )
      },
      error => {
        if (error.error.status === false) {
          this.emailError =  error.error.errors.email;
          this.passwordError =  error.error.errors.password;
        };
      }

    )
  }
```

**Http.service.ts** -> here is where i need to retrieve the updated value of the token

```
  access_token;

   getSubject(){
        this.userService.access_token.subscribe(
            token => {
                this.access_token = token
            });
        return this.access_token;
    }

  setLogin(): Observable<any[]> {
        this.getSubject();
        const url = 'http://url';
        const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.access_token);

            return this.httpClient.post<any[]>(url, { headers: httpHeaders });
    }
```

Comment: please put your userService code

Comment: i did, i just forgot to correctly mark it as code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to treat the `this.userService.access_token` as asynchronous all the time.

When the `return this.access_token;` is called, `this.access_token = token` has not been called yet.

You need to chain on this subscription to be able to make the request with the token.

```
setLogin(): Observable<any[]> {

    const url = 'http://url';

    return this.userService.access_token
        .take(1)
        .concatMap((access_token) => {
            const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
                .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);

            return this.httpClient.post<any[]>(url, { headers: httpHeaders });
        });
}
```

You could also wrap things up into separate methods to make things looks nicer, but this should work for you.

`take(1)` will make sure that this only happens once. Since you use `BehaviorSubject` for the token, it should already be there and happen instantly.

Inside `concatMap()` then the call is made and the `concatMap` makes sure that the result get's propagated back same way as it would if you just returned a `this.httpClient.post()` result.

Edit - a note:

When calling `setLogin()` you need to subscribe to returned value, otherwise it won't get called.

```
this.httpService.setLogin().subscribe();
```

If you don't want to receive any value from the function or to know when it finished, you could also `.subscribe()` right after `concatMap()`. You'd need to remove the first `return`.

RXJS pipes are "lazy" and won't produce any value until the pipe is subscribed to. The `access_token` would not produce any value, therefore the `post()` to the server is not being called.

Comment: thank you but your solution does not seem to work either. I'm wondering if subscribe is not missing somewhere after concatMap as this.userService.access_token is a BehavioralSubject. Or is concatMap somehow a substitite for subsrcibe() ?

Comment: You're right. You do need to subscribe to the `concatMap` somewhere, otherwise it won't work. You could do that where you call the `setLogin` method or directly inside. I've expanded my answer. Happy coding :-)

Comment: @BartłomiejBlue Hi, has this worked for you with a subscribe?

Comment: Yes indeed thank you so much i forgot to answer to you:)